# Angular: How can I get access to one of many svg elements?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I just started to learn Angular for my project. First of all I was looking for was some way to get access to any of my svg elements to dynamically change it's style. So I used ViewChild and ElementRef.

From html:

```
<svg><g ...>
<polygon #someTag1 id = "s0" class="st27" points="67,46 58,46 58,56 67,56 67,70 86,70 86,32 67,32"/>
<polygon #someTag2 id = "s1" class="st27" points="104,46 113,46 113,56 104,56 104,70 85,70 85,32 104,32"/>
<polygon #someTag3 id = "s2" class="st27" points="147,46 138,46 138,56 147,56 147,70 166,70 166,32 147,32"/>
```

From component:

```
@ViewChild("someTag1") someTag1: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.someTag1.nativeElement.removeAttribute("class");
  this.someTag1.nativeElement.setAttribute("class", "shining");
}
```

And it works as I planned.

The problem is that I want to change one element from group of a lot of different elements, not only for #someTag1. So I guess, when I have 260 different polygons, in this solution, I need to create 260 ViewChilds...

I thought I should use ViewChildren and create separate components or class for my svg elements but I don't really have any idea how to do it. Or maybe there is a different way?

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are creating the 200+ polygons by iterating over some sort of list.

**some.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `<polygon #poly *ngFor="let item of items" />`
})
export class SomeComponent
  items = Array(260)

  @ViewChildren('poly') refs: QueryList<ElementRef> ;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // do something with the polygons
  }
```

Comment: I have a ready SVG map consisting of those polygons and I only need to operate on them.

Comment: I don't really understand this   template: `<polygon #poly *ngFor="let item of items" />`. I'm not creating this polygons map, I have it already, drawn by someone else, placed in 'templateUrl: './component.html''  and I need to operate on this by getting access to each one of them.